# MarkLogic - Error with loading pipeline for content processing

Tags: marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version - 9.0-6.2 (on windows)

I am following the guide (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/quickStart) to perform the sample exercise provided. After installing CPF on data-hub-FINAL (with data-hub-TRIGGERS as the triggers db), I created a pipeline XML document (as given in example) in my C drive at directory C:\copyright. Then on the admin console, I navigated to databases -->data-hub-FINAL--> Content Processing--> Pipelines --> Load, and provided below values.

```
directory : C:\copyright
filter : *.xml
source : (file system)
```

However, when I click 'Ok', I am getting error message 'Invalid input: No readable XML files found:'

I verified that the pipeline xml is present and valid in the directory C:\copyright.

Any inputs appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marklogic could not read the xml document because of non UTF-8 content in the document, as shown below.

```
<state-transition>
  <annotation>
    When a document containing ‘book' as a root element is created, 
    add a ‘copyright' statement.
  </annotation>
```

For now, I removed the annotation from the xml document and successfully loaded the pipeline.

Comment: There are command-line tools and most common text editors that allow saving text and xml files as valid UTF-8. I've used `iconv` on command-line, and notepad++ and textmate are examples of editors..